# How to open SharePoint designer from command-line with a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I'm working on a Visual Studio Add-in to edit files in SharePoint. From this Add-in I would like to be able to open SharePoint Designer with a specific SharePoint site.
Finding the application is no problem, its folder is in registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\SharePoint Designer\InstallRoot, and the application is called SPDesign.exe.

I could only find a command-line switch to open a page (see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101487151033.aspx), not to open a site.

If I open a page like spdesign.exe /n http://myserver/pages/default.aspx, the page is opened with a name Untitled_1.aspx, and at the left side you don't see the site explorer.

Any ideas on how to automate the opening of a site, and if possible also the opening of a page in the site, with the site navigator on  the left side and the actual page opened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think to open a site, you just pass in the URL of the site with with no switch.

spdesign.exe http://My_server/My_site

Comment: You are absolutely right! This was the first thing I tried, but it didn't work. Just tried it with my machine rebooted in the mean time, and it works! I think SPD was is a "strange state" when I tested:-) Thanks!